# What do I do with Adventurers?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

It looks like once a day I can call for adventurers online or I can get them through spotpass or StreetPass.

What are Adventurers for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/rumbleworld/streetpass.shtml):

> When you first pass other players, you will have to rescue their Mii during a small mission. Then, these Mii players will show up as you play and can offer you a variety of bonuses.
>
> - X Attack: Boosts the Attack of your Pokémon
> - X Defense: Boosts the Defense of your Pokémon
> - X Speed: Boosts the Speed of your Pokémon
> - Potion: Heals your Pokémon
>
> You may also receive a PokéDiamond from them.
>
> With the StreetPass and SpotPass features, you will also receive PokéDiamonds for free when you achieve certain milestones for it. This includes both StreetPass and SpotPass features. Each PokéDiamond batch can be redeemed just once from the Shop.

It's worth noting that these features will bring various other players from the Internet into your overall plaza.
Sometimes their Miis can send you to recently played area for 500P or a bunch of PokeDiamonds, depending on the number of stars that area had.